# XML to XSD using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, xsd

I am trying to load below XML into SQL Server table using SSIS.
Original XML:

```
<RESULTS>
    <SEARCHRESULT RECORDS="3014">
        <ROW ROWNUM="1" PKField="EntityCounter">
            <COLUMN COLNUM="1" NAME="EntityCounter" DATATYPE="number">1234</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN COLNUM="2" NAME="Reference ID" DATATYPE="string">5678</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN COLNUM="3" NAME="Name" DATATYPE="string">XYZ</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN COLNUM="4" NAME="Entity Type" DATATYPE="string">LMN</COLUMN>
        </ROW>
    </SEARCHRESULT>
</RESULTS>
```

The destination table has 4 columns: EntityCounter, ReferenceID, Name and EntityType.
When I create XSD for such file, I don’t get the expected output.
XML source generates four columns at the output:  ROW_ID, RWONUM, PKField and SEARCHRESULT_Id.

I was able to load the data when I modified the XML as below:
Modified XML:

```
<RESULTS>
    <SEARCHRESULT RECORDS="3014">
        <ROW ROWNUM="1" PKField="EntityCounter">
            <EntityCounter>1234</EntityCounter>
            <ReferenceID>5678</ReferenceID>
            <Name>XYZ</Name>
            <EntityType>LMN</EntityType>
        </ROW>
    </SEARCHRESULT>
</RESULTS>
```

When I create and use XSD for above file, XML source generates seven columns at the output:  ROWNUM, PKFiled, EntityCounter, ReferenceID, Name, EntityType and SEARCHRESULT_Id.

Is it possible to generate similar output using original XML?

Comment: Two possible options would be to use xslt to modify the xml before processing, or use a pivot transform in the data flow to put the rows onto columns.  I am not familiar with xsd enough to know if there is some magic that can be done there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @MarkWojciechowicz for suggesting an option to use XSLT..!
I was able to transform original xml into required format using below xslt code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="COLUMN[@NAME]">
        <xsl:element name="{concat('Col_',translate(@NAME,' ',''))}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Modified XML can be loaded using SSIS.